# how to read nucleotide sequence of a DNAstring

Tags: r, string

i'm new on R.
I have an assembly genome and I read the stringset

```
x <- readDNAStringSet("GCA_000146045.2_R64_genomic.fna", format = "fasta")
```

Then I obtained this

```
    A DNAStringSet instance of length 16
           width seq                                            enter code here   names               
    [1]  230218 CCACACCACACCCACACACCCAC...GGTGTGGGTGTGGTGTGTGTGGG BK006935.2 TPA_in...
    [2]  813184 AAATAGCCCTCATGTACGTCTCC...GTGGGTGTGGTGTGTGGGTGTGT BK006936.2 TPA_in...
    [3]  316620 CCCACACACCACACCCACACCAC...GTGTGGTGGGTGTGGTGTGTGTG BK006937.2 TPA_in...
    [4] 1531933 ACACCACACCCACACCACACCCA...TAAAGGTAGTAAGTAGCTTTTGG BK006938.2 TPA_in...
    [5]  576874 CGTCTCCTCCAAGCCCTGTTGTC...GTTTCATTTTCATTTTTTTTTTT BK006939.2
TPA_in...
...     ... ...
    [12] 1078177 CACACACACACACCACCCACACA...GGAGACGTACATGAGGGCTATTT BK006945.2 TPA_in...
    [13]  924431 CCACACACACACCACACCCACAC...GTGGGTGTGGTGTGTGTGTGGGG BK006946.2 TPA_in...
    [14]  784333 CCGGCTTTCTGACCGAAATTAAA...GTGTGTGTGGGTGTGGTGTGGGT BK006947.3
TPA_in...
     [15] 1091291 ACACCACACCCACACCACACCCA...GAGAGTGTGTGGGTGTGGTGTGT BK006948.2 TPA_in...
     [16]  948066 AAATAGCCCTCATGTACGTCTCC...TTTTTTTTAATTTCGGTCAGAAA BK006949.2 TPA_in...
```

The next operation that i made was the sorting of the width

```
 width(x)
[1]  230218  813184  316620 1531933  576874  270161 1090940  562643  439888
[10]  745751  666816 1078177  924431  784333 1091291  948066



 sort(width(x))
[1]  230218  270161  316620  439888  562643  576874  666816  745751  784333
[10]  813184  924431  948066 1078177 1090940 1091291 1531933
```

Now how can I read the nucleotide sequence in therms of letters of the string 745751? Supposing that I hAVE a bigger genome and I know only the length of a string of my interest but i don't know where it is exactly located whitout sorting, how can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

Extract all `DNAString`s inside `x` that have a `width` of 745751:

```
x[width(x) == 745751]
```

To convert to `character`

```
as.character(x[width(x) == 745751])
```

---

Here is an example based on some minimal sample data

```
x <- DNAStringSet(x = c("AGTCTATCTA", "ACTAA", "ATGAA"))
```

Extract all sequences of length 5:

```
x[width(x) == 5]
#A DNAStringSet instance of length 2
#    width seq
#[1]     5 ACTAA
#[2]     5 ATGAA
```

Convert to a `character` vector

```
as.character(x[width(x) == 5])
#[1] "ACTAA" "ATGAA"
```

Comment: I have another problem. How can I check if this sequence has the identical nucleotide sequence of another string of a different string set? I must check if there are differences, I mean, I have to compare x with y but y belongs to another dnastringset from another fasta file. Thank you

Comment: @Su.Doku I'm not entirely clear what you're asking. Are you looking for *identical* sequences in two `DNAStringSet` objects? Or for *similar* sequences? Either way, SO generally favours one question at a time. It might be best to ask your follow up as a new question; also please include reproducible sample data similar to what I do in my post.

Comment: Ok I'll do it. Thank you!